Reduction formula for $\int e^x(\sin^nx) dx$

Reduction formula for $\int e^x\sin^nx\,dx$

Attempt:
Let $$I_n = \int e^x\sin^nx\,dx$$
By integration by parts,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\ I_n &=\sin^nx\,e^x- \int e^xn\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,dx \\
&=\sin^nx\,e^x- n\int e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,dx \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and I got stuck here. Do I integrate by parts again? Or are there other methods to make the $I_n$ appear again to complete the formula?

Please include your attempt to "integrate by parts again", and compare your result with the bottom of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae

If I integrate by parts this will become extremely tedious and difficult to solve. Therefore I'm here asking if that's ok or if there're other methods.

Don't be afraid, just give it a try.

Here is a full proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitive_of_Exponential_of_a_x_by_Power_of_Sine_of_b_x

Just a question tho - couldn't an exact form be obtained using $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$?

Starting from, $$
 I_n=\sin^nx\,e^x- n\int e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,dx 
$$
We perform integration by parts on $\int e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,dx$ to get
$$
 I_n=\sin^nx\,e^x- ne^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x+n\int e^x((n-1)\sin^{n-2}x\cos^2 x-\sin^{n}x)\,dx. 
$$
But, using $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$, we get
$$
 I_n=\sin^nx\,e^x- ne^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,+(n^2-n)I_{n-2}-n^2I_n. 
$$
Rearranging for $I_n$ gives
$$
 I_n=\frac{1}{n^2+1}\left[\sin^nx\,e^x- ne^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,+(n^2-n)I_{n-2}\right]. 
$$

Instead of integrating by parts you can as well use derivatives. We have
$$ (e^x\sin^nx)'=e^x\sin^nx+ne^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x$$ Thus $$e^x\sin^nx=I_n+n\int e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,dx$$ Next $$(e^x\sin^{n-1}\cos x)'\\ = e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x+(n-1)e^x\sin^{n-2}x\cos^2x -e^x\sin^{n}x\\ =
e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x-ne^x\sin^nx+(n-1)e^x\sin^{n-2}x$$ Thus $$e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x=\int e^x\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\,dx -nI_n+(n-1)I_{n-2}$$ Plugging it into  the first integral formula gives a relation between $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}.$
